# how to add few columns data and copy it to another excel file in one column

Tags: excel, copy

I want the data from Financials – Flat Workbook, to be copied into destination workbook, as per the SPRF number matching with either the spreadsheet name or column B2 as per the months on the Destination workbook, so for the current month it will be actual and for the remaining months it will be forecast. It will be as per the resource role, Resource Name, Project for activity and application.
Copy data from one workbook to another workbook

For example – I want to update 46441A, with SA, Dev…etc hours from Flat file, so if I have to do it manually, I will go on Flat file spreadsheet, check for 153220 Quality Assurance, Resource Name, 46441A and ISET, take the total Actual for current month and forecast for remaining months and will copy it in dashboard workbook.

All correct Res Role for SA, DEV, QA and all will start with 153220.

Comment: Use concatenate? http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat.php Because I'm not really getting your question.